# Running Windows Azure .vhd locally with VirtualBox on mac os host

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtualization, azure, vhd

I downloaded a detached disk from Windows Azure (it contains Ubuntu Linux).

After download i renamed `abcd` to `abcd.vhd` as per azure suggestion and tried to mount on a virtual machine created on VirtualBox (MacOS Host).

The machine turns on but it gets stuck during boot. I read that azure machines are powered by Hyper-V so I tried with hyper-v virtualization within virtual box but nothing seems to work.

Anyone had experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: You've set up a Hyper-V server VM in VirtualBox and are trying to run your abcd VM nested in Hyper-V?  Note, that selecting "Hyper-V" under Paravirtualization Interface is not the same as running the Hyper-V hypervisor.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you hint here. Yes I tried Hyper-V because the machine doesn't start with default settings. Have you ever had to run an Azure image loclaly? Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my own question for everyone facing the same issue I had.

Actually, it is possible to run the .vhd image locally on VirtualBox as long as the virtual machine is configured as follows:

- PAE/NX disabled within "processor" tab
- Motherbord chipset set to ICH9
- Motherbord I/O APIC enabled
- Storage should be set as SATA
- You need to enable serial port on Port 1

Base configuration for me was Linux Ubuntu because it was Linux Ubuntu image, I suppose the same applies for any other distro.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried the above settings with no luck. Still getting stuck in boot (dracut-initqueue starting timeout scripts). Any chance you could extend your answer with all available settings that worked for you?

Comment: Turns out that with VirtualBox 6.1.26 on Windows the VHD disk boots fine! No settings needed to be changed

Comment: Furthermore, I found that the storage controller works when set to IDE

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a Mac, may I suggest standing up a new server in Azure that is either a [Dv3 or Ev3](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-dv3-and-ev3-vm-sizes/) series VM?  These VMs support nested virtualization and will allow you to install HyperV on them.  From there you can download the VHD and boot it (I have done this in the past before we had serial console access).  I'm not sure you will be able to get a HyperV machine to work properly in Virtualbox.

[How to enable nested virtualization in an Azure VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization)